# Should mistakes in questions be fixed if answers address the question as it stands?

Tags: discussion, editing

[Why do we have same chord but different name?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/70191/45266)

I recently saw this post and its revision history. It got me thinking: this post has what is likely a mistake in it, but all the answers (which are all really old, by the way) address the question with the error.

(for those curious, I approved/imporved an edit before I noticed the answers, so I rolled back)

**Should this be edited to fix the chord symbol?** I'm leaning strongly towards "no", since I doubt it would do our site or the question any good, but I wanted to hear your opinions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original edit changed **Cdim7** to **C half-dim7**. This was a bad edit in my opinion. Full disclosure: I wrote what is currently the top-voted answer on that question.

Although the OP did write "sorry, this question is wrong...." in the comments, it is unclear in what way OP saw the question as wrong. The OP never made any edits or clarifying comments, and it is unclear that changing **Cdim7** to **C<sup>∅</sup>** would meet the original intent. It could be that OP mistakenly thought that **dim** chords and **m7♭5** chords are the same thing. The edit would seem to reduce the question to one of chord symbols, but we don't know if that is what OP meant to ask.

Addtionally, there are some answers (all less than a year old, not "really old") which address the incorrect statement. Editing this out invalidates part of these answers.

As a general rule, I tend to reject edits that correct "mistakes" that may be part of some misunderstanding on the poster's part. Correcting these mistakes in an edit can change the question, and edits should not change questions. Correcting such mistakes should be part of an *answer*. It can be difficult to tell when such errors are just typos; it is best if OP corrects the mistake themselves, or indicates in comments that it is a typo.

Comment: Just to add to this - if a question has a big mistake, it's much better if we can put it on hold while that is corrected - this stops answers being posted that may be invalidated when the question is corrected. Once relevant edits have been made, we can reopen and folks can answer.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya -- you don't need to keep leaving comments here and on the original question letting everyone know that you have flagged the question; the flag is enough. IAC, there is a lack of clarity in the question, but many good questions are a bit unclear, reflecting a lack of clarity on concepts in the asker. In my opinion, this question shows such a lack of clarity in the OP; I and others answered the question in such a way that OP's needs would be met, choosing pedagogy over pedantry.